# winHTTP GET request C++

Tags: c++, get, winhttp, winhttprequest

I'll get right to the point.

- This is what a browser request looks like

  GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
- This is what winHTTP does

  GET http://site.com/index.html HTTP/1.1

Is there any I can get the winHTTP request to be the same format as the regular one?
I'm using VC++ 2008 if it makes any difference

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I am curious as to why you wish this?

Comment: Since you should send Host: site.com in a separate line and only send path in the GET? Actually after reading the RFC it say if site stated in the GET URI Host: should be ignored.

Comment: atm my code is a c/p from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270%28VS.85%29.aspx I already tried setting the url to /index.html and then manually setting the Host: header but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have some non-transparent proxy configured on the machine (either local like Fiddler or corporate) - in that case, the request *will* have the full uri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
// Specify an HTTP server.
if (hSession)
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.example.com",
                               INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", L"/path/resource.html",
                                   NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                   WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
                                   WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

// Send a request.
if (hRequest)
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                                   0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
                                   0, 0);
```

Can you post these three calls from your code?

Note that the full URL is split in two - the host name is specified in the `WinHttpConnect` call, but the relative resource path is specified in the `WinHttpOpenRequest` call (as the `pwszObjectName` parameter). Based on your comment, it seems you are specifying the full URL in the `WinHttpConnect` call.